# Pass parameters to exe Simulink

Tags: matlab, exe, simulink

I am running simulations with an exe generated from a Simulink model using the Embedded Coder. I would like to pass parameters (gain values...) to this exe so that I don't have to compile every time I want to change one value. 
To call the exe, I'm using the Matlab function `system`.
Do you have any clue how to do that ?

Comment: "To call the exe, I'm using the Matlab function system." That's the part I don't understand. I usually call the exe by double clicking on it. How do you do it exactly?

Comment: If you can rebuild the exe you can use the api mentioned in doc at https://www.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ug/use-c-api-to-access-model-parameters.html to access parameters.

Comment: @Trilarion I am using a Matlab environment to set paths, run the simulation through the exe and plot the results...

Comment: But how do you call the exe through matlab? Do you use [system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html)? Also, how many parameters do you have? Are they scalars or matrices?

Comment: @Trilarion Sorry I added my comment by mistake. Here is what's next : 
So far, I run my simulation by executing the line "system(mymodel.exe);" and I would like to do something like "system(mymodel.exe param.txt)"

Comment: @Navan I tried using the information you mentionned, but I didn't succeed in using the capi_ModifyModelParameter function that seems to do what I need. And I can't find example anywhere.

Comment: There is an example file pointed from that doc page edit(fullfile(matlabroot,'/rtw/c/src/rtw_capi_examples.c')) that contains code that modifies parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [rapid simulation (RSim) system target](https://se.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/rapid-simulations.html) to create the executable, you can achieve this by [creating a `.mat` file](https://se.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/rapid-simulations.html#bqny0b5) that contains a structure defining the parameters and call the executable [using this format](https://se.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/rapid-simulations.html#brdeu57):

```
model.exe -p param.mat
```

To create that structure you need to call [`rsimgetrtp`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/ecoder/ref/rsimgetrtp.html) function and then fill the desired values and save it in the `.mat` file.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the ert compilation option, and I would like to stick with it. The method described in the comments above should work but I haven't been able to so far